# OpenERP strange date time issue

Tags: odoo

I am using `OpenERP version 6.1` and `OpenERP web client`. The `OpenERP` server is installed in my laptop hence both server and the client on the same machine.

The issue I am facing is that it looks like `OpenERP` treats my local time as current `UTC` time.
My time zone in Windows is set to `UTC+5:30 hours (Asia/Colombo)` and the current time is `11:00 AM`. When I see the current time from OpenERP using,

```
  'date_created': lambda *a: datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
```

It shows me 03/29/2012 16:30:24 instead of correct time 11:00 AM. My observation is that OpenERP get the current time and add 5 hours 30 minutes to current time and shows me. So, OpenERP assumes my current local time as the current UTC time.

I must install the software at clients site but without this fixed, I cannot install.

Answer (score 5):

The [OpenERP v6.1 Release Notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OfJzGUsw6fV9Z0uThx1aANC1coN7yuIaBNjFKBdaaCA/edit?hl=en_US&pli=1#heading=h.cc1vqtq9lmj6) state that now the server and database work exclusively with UTC dates, ignoring the OS timezone settings.

The timezone conversion is made dynamically by the client:

- the Web client uses the browser setting (which usually matches the client machine settings)
- the GTK client uses the setting in the user preferences.

Answer (score 3):

There is one golden rule for datetime fields in 6.1 addons code:
 "`ALWAYS work in UTC - compute in UTC - save in UTC`"
The UTC values will be properly converted to local time when the result is
diplayed in a client-side form.